# Query date field in Yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

In SQL, I might do something like this

```
"WHERE DATEPART(month, my_date_field) = 8"
```

to grab the rows where month in my_date_field = 8.

I am unsure how this syntax translates into Yii2.
I have

```
$query = Fees::find();
$fees = $query->all();
```

How do I use the WHERE clause on the date field within that $query ?

Comment: You are not using MySQL. Right? As http://stackoverflow.com/a/13402434/2559712

Comment: Thx, the DATEPART was wrong also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in yii2 allows text in where clause as below

```
$fees = Fees::find()
    ->where("DATEPART(month, my_date_field) = 8")
    ->all();
```

You may chain other 'sql functions' like order, group by , limit etc like this as well.