# mysql array selecting and sum values

Tags: mysql, arrays

I own an array that three records containing:

```
value     datetime
2       03/03/2015 14:34:00
4       03/03/2015 14:36:00
5       03/03/2015 13:34:00
```

I want to select the records that are on time 14 and sum them. In the above example would be 4 + 2 = 6

How can I do this?

```
$sql ="SELECT amperagem, data FROM tomada WHERE date(data) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";// 
mysql_select_db('localiza');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($retval);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_BOTH)){    
$hour= substr(($row['data']),11, 2);
```

Comment: how does your table definition look like? do you want to sum all values at a certain hour, regardless the day (date) ? I mean, time 14:xx:xx can occur in your table many time on different days all year.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get yourself the value through a single SQL query:

Be sure to read up on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

So to get all records with a datetime containing 14:XX:XX

```
SELECT value FROM tomada WHERE HOUR(data) = 14;
```

Now simply get the rows like you did and retrieve the 'value' per row and add them up

```
$res = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$returnObjects = array();
        if ($res == null) {
            return $returnObjects;      
        }       
        while(!is_null($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))){
            $returnObjects[] = $row;
        }
$returnArray = mysql_fetch_array($returnObjects);
$sum = 0;
for($row = 0, $size = count($returnArray); $row < $size; $row++){
        $sum += $returnArray[$row][0]; //Note 0 is the value you need
}
return $sum;
```

Note it can be done in less lines of codes with less steps but I find this helps reading what i'm doing. Also some additional checks if certain objects are NULL or values are invalid is recommended.

Comment: Did you try to run the SQL in your PhpMyAdmin? Hmm I can check the SQL myself. 
Also check if you need mysql OR mysqli.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402012/select-row-by-datepart

Fixed the main answer for you, should work now. Works for me in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: I found that line but don't works too, you know where is the problem?      $sql = "SELECT SUM(amperagem) AS soma, HOUR(data) as hora FROM tomada WHERE data >='15:00:00' AND data <= '15:59:59'";

Comment: When you SELECT SUM as soma, you get a different value to extract.
SELECT value FROM tomada WHERE HOUR(data) = 15; this should be what you want

Answer (score 0):

The sql is as simple as:

> select sum(value) from tomada where  hour(datetime) = 14;